# What's your "best" backup strategy for multi-hundred-gb tables?

Tags: mysql

TL;DR What is "your" best backup strategy to bring multi-hundred-gigabytes database back online in (hopefully) less than a day. Ha.

Adding to the TL;DR, it *seems* like raid1/10 is the "best" solution overall realistically, but I digress.

Currently, we have all of our InnoDB tables as their own file, and currently do a daily (full database) backup as well as hourly (billing table), where each table is its own SQL output.
However, we're starting to realize that our multi-hundred-gigabyte tables will take 10+ hours (each) to restore if we need to. I know all the tricks, the absolute fastest we seem to be able to get rows inserted on an import is ~15-20k rows/sec.

I know I can do CSV exports and really cut down the import time but that doesn't seem like a real legitimate backup plan either for a bunch of other reasons.

I know I can do physical backups and just backup all of the files and that doesn't seem like a terrible thing - although I think it would be a nightmare if we ever needed to restore a single table or even if we ever needed to restore a whole server and you don't just slap over the tables `.ibd` file and restart. Even with the physical route, I also don't want to lock tables or shutdown the server while backing up the physical files either.

Even if I went to the "extreme" and setup a replica as the backup, that's also not really a "backup" either though.

Comment: LVM will take a minute or two, regardless of size.